# Use sessionscoped or requestscoped for signup

Tags: jsf, scope

i wanted to ask whether to use @sessionscoped or @requestscoped for my signup page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: your tagginf was way to broad, I 'corrected' it.